# How can I map request object including updatedLocalDateTime to object in Spring Boot through MapStruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a problem about mapping request to entity through MapStruct.

I have no idea to map createdAt and updateAt.

How can I do that?

Here is the UserRequest shown below

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserRequest {

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
}
```

Here is the Mapper used MapStruct

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true) // My Issue
    @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true) // My Issue
    void updateRequestToUser(UserRequest request, @MappingTarget User user);
}
```

Here is the base entity shown below

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

Here is the User show below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class User extends BaseEntity {
   ....
   private String username;
   private String firstName;
}
```

Comment: Your UserRequest class has no fields named `createdAt` or `updatedAt` to map to.

Comment: @lane.maxwell It is a process of updating a user as you can use. My issue is how to map it to User Entity.

Comment: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_reusing_mapping_configurations